# Why copy constructor was called twice in following program?

Tags: c++

Why copy constructor is being called twice in below program. Is this correct behaviour? If i dont use initializer list, Its calling Default constructor of A.

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(){cout<<"A()\n";}
    A(const A &a){cout<<"A(A)\n";}
};
class B
{
    private:
    A aa;
    public:
    B(A bb):aa(bb)
    { 
        cout<<"B(A)\n";
    }
};
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    A cc;
    B b(cc);
}
```

Output:

```
A()
A(A)
A(A)
B(A)
```

Comment: You couldn't have chosen more confusing variable names, you know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time it is called when `cc` is passed to the constructor `B::B(A)` of `B`.

The second time it is called when `b.aa` is initialized with `bb` in the member initializer list of the constructor `B::B(A)`.

Comment: You could add that to avoid this behaviour, `B`'s constructor could take a reference to `A`.